# Ffmpeg: suppress warning when writing to a single image

Tags: ffmpeg, bash-scripting, png

Somewhere in the more recent versions, ffmpeg started printing this warning when I process png files:

```sh
ffmpeg -i "src.png" -vf "$vf" "dst.png"
```

> The specified filename './dst.png' does not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
> Use a pattern such as %03d for an image sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to write a single image.

I wasn't able to figure out how to use `-update` and `-frames:v 1` properly, my various attempts only resulting in errors. And I couldn't find relevant documentation on how to use these.

What am I supposed to do in order to supress the warning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
ffmpeg -i "src.png" -vf "$vf" -vframes 1 "dst.png"
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i "src.png" -vf "$vf" -update true "dst.png"
```

The former is preferable, although it doesn't matter when working with a single image input.

Comment: The first one still showed me the warning, but the second one works. Thanks.